# Can I use `FindRoot` to find roots of 'non-mathematical' functions?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I have a system of two linear differential equations, where the initial conditions depend on a parameter. I want to find the value for this parameter $\lambda$ such that the solution evaluated in one particular point $x_0$ takes some value (in particular, the quotient between the components of the solution vector).

In order to achieve this, I have build a function that admits as input a value for this parameter $\lambda$, uses it to solve the system and then returns the value at the desired point $x_0$. I called this, `solver[lambda]`.

So I was wondering if I could use `FindRoot` in the followoing way

```
FindRoot[solver[lambda]-value,{lambda,lambdaInit}]
```

where `value` is the value I want and `lambdaInit` is an initial value for $\lambda$ that I know is close to the desired one.

Does this make sense? Maybe depending on the method applied by `FindRoot`?

Comment: You should consider looking at `ParametricNDSolve`, which returns a family of solutions to the differential equations parameterized by some quantity, which in your case would be $\lambda$. That way, you get a function back that can be used inside `FindRoot`.

Comment: Do what march said, but I wrote a more generally applicable answer anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can.

[Define `solver` so that it doesn't evaluate for symbolic arguments:](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037)

```
solver[lambda_?NumericQ] := ...
```

Then just use `FindRoot` normally.  It will select the method automatically.

It is also true that not all methods can be used.  Newton's method requires the (symbolic) derivative but e.g. the secant method doesn't.

You'll find detailed documentation in the second section here:

- http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationOverview.html